Is enumeration over custom union type possible?
Having a disjoint union type like this:
type yolo = | A | B | C

Is it possible in OCaml to iterate/enumerate over each possible value of type yolo without prior knowledge of how many/what these values are?
What I want to achieve is a function that takes a type and returns a list with all of its values. For example:
let yolos = extractor yolo
val yolos : yolo list = [A; B; C]

(I am looking for a way to implement extractor function from the above snippet)
In F# my goal is achievable with something similar to this:
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

type yolo =
    | A
    | B
    | C
let yolos = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<yolo>


@glennsl yes it does, in fact I marked my own question as a duplicate of the one you mentioned. The only advantage over that one is my F# snippet I guess.

Yes, it is possible. It looks like you're looking for Jane Street's ppx_enumerate which does exactly this, even working with polymorphic types.
